# Libvirt, Qemu VM problem with keyboard

Tags: qemu, libvirt

I am building a system comprised of Linux 5.9.18 and Busybox.

I am able to get a shell open. But, my keyboard does not work.

I am using libvirt with Qemu.

```
My kernel config is configured as the following (allnoconfig, and then the settings below):
[*] 64-bit kernel
-> General setup
  -> Configure standard kernel features
[*] Enable support for printk
-> General setup
[*] Initial RAM filesystem and RAM disk (initramfs/initrd) support
-> Executable file formats / Emulations
[*] Kernel support for ELF binaries
[*] Kernel support for scripts starting with #!
-> Device Drivers
  -> Character devices
[*] Enable TTY
-> Device Drivers
  -> Character devices
    -> Serial drivers
[*] 8250/16550 and compatible serial support
[*]   Console on 8250/16550 and compatible serial port
-> File systems
  -> Pseudo filesystems
[*] /proc file system support
[*] sysfs file system support
-> Kernel hacking                                                     
    -> Compile-time checks and compiler options 
[*] Debug filesystem
-> Kernel hacking   
[*] Early printk
```

I edited my VM's XML file like so:

```
<device>
...
    <input type='evdev'>
      <source dev='/dev/input/by-id/usb-Dell_Dell_USB_Keyboard-event-kbd' grab='all' repeat='on'/>
    </input>
...
</device>
```

The keyboard seems to catch on to the VM window, but it does not type anything when I press any keys. Not sure what the issue could be. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!